# BinarySearchTree - isBalanced() method get NullPointerException - Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I'm currently studying data structure and I'm at BinarySearchTree now.

Lab Question: "Consider a method for a binary search tree that decides whether the tree is height balanced."

When I do the lab, somehow I get NullPointerException in the Test output. I dont know why and where I get a Null. NetBean says the error is from BinarySearchTree.isBalanced()

```
    int leftHeight = left.getHeight();
    int rightHeight = right.getHeight();

    return (tree.getData() == null ) || (isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right) 
                                       && Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) <= 1);
```

Can you guys please help me?

Thanks a lot

This is my isBalanced() method:

```
public boolean isBalanced(){
    return isBalanced(root);
}
private boolean isBalanced(BinaryNode<T> tree){
    BinaryNode<T> left = tree.getLeftChild();
    BinaryNode<T> right = tree.getRightChild();


    int leftHeight = left.getHeight();
    int rightHeight = right.getHeight();

    return (tree.getData() == null ) || (isBalanced(left) && isBalanced(right) 
                                       && Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) <= 1);
}
```

And this is the getHeight() method in the BinaryNode class

```
public int getHeight(){
     return getHeight(this); // call private getHeight
} // end getHeight

private int getHeight(BinaryNode<T> node){
     int height = 0;

     if (node != null)
         height = 1 + Math.max(getHeight(node.left), 
             getHeight(node.right));

     return height;
 } // end getHeight
```

Comment: Somewhere, you have a variable that isn't initialized, and on which you are calling a method. Check out which variable that is, and make sure it is initialized before calling methods.

Comment: Maybe you should also learn to debug through your code. It's pretty easy and you will learn an art you will use through-out your career.

Answer (score 1):

The left and right children may be `null` in your program, so in `isBalanced(BinaryNode<T> tree)` you should first judge `tree != null` otherwise `tree.getLeftChild();` may throw a NullPointerException.